# How can you have a background image with text on top on a button on tk?

Tags: python, button, tkinter

I am trying to make tk buttons look better by adding a button background. The issue is, I can use an image or text, but not both, for a tk button.

How can you have both?

This is what I have tried:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

print("I ran")

master = Tk()

canvas_width = 800
canvas_height = 400
window = Canvas(master, 
           width=canvas_width,
           height=canvas_height)

img = Image.open("images/button_black.png").resize((80,40))
ph_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)

l = Label(master, text='Button', image=ph_image, compound=CENTER, fg="white")
l.pack(side=LEFT)

button = Button ( master, image=l)

window.pack()

mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use both an image and text you must set the `compound` option. From the [canonical documentation](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/options.htm#M-compound):

> Specifies if the widget should display text and bitmaps/images at the same time, and if so, where the bitmap/image should be placed relative to the text. Must be one of the values **none**, **bottom**, **top**, **left**, **right**, or **center**. For example, the (default) value **none** specifies that the bitmap or image should (if defined) be displayed instead of the text, the value **left** specifies that the bitmap or image should be displayed to the left of the text, and the value **center** specifies that the bitmap or image should be displayed on top of the text.

Example:

The following example uses this image:

[image]

The program renders like this when using `compound="center"`:

[image]

```
import tkinter as tk

image_data = '''
    R0lGODdhyABkAKIAAAAAAP8mAP/7AP///wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACH5BAkAAAQALAA
    AAADIAGQAAAP/KLrc/jDKSau9OOvNu/9gKI5kaZ5oqq5s675wLM90bd94ru987/
    /AoHBILBqPyKRyyWw6n9CodEqtWq/YrHbL7Xq/4LB4TC6bz+i0es1uu9/wuHxOl
    wTu+Lx+z+8H6jZ+goOEg4AnhYmKi3yHHIyQkZGOE5KWl5CUCpicnYx1nqGihHCj
    pqd+a6irrHlnrbCwY7G0sl+1uKxeubyoXL3AplnBxMJWxciex8nMmFXN0JJU0dS
    ZUtXYiVPZ3ILb3eB63+Hk4+Tg5ufc6erY0+3Zz/Du8vPQV/bRw/nFv/zAu/7lAi
    Ow1qyCq14hFKVqobM3Dj/RiUhKE0U8miIUzIihNh3HEPo+toglsqTJkyhTqlzJs
    qXLlzBjypxJs6bNmzhz6tzJs6fPn0CDCh1KtKjRo0iTKlWZAAA7
'''

root = tk.Tk()
image = tk.PhotoImage(data=image_data)
label = tk.Button(root, image=image, text="Hello, world", compound="center")
label.pack(padx=20, pady=20)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: This doesn't put the text OVER the image, which is what I want

Comment: @Makogan:  yes it does, if you use "center'.

Comment: "center specifies that the bitmap or image should be displayed on top of the text"
On top, as in, hiding it

Comment: @Makogan: I think in this context, "on top of" simply means that they are centered around the same point. I urge you to try it.

Comment: It seems to be a problem with my current setup, copy pasted your code and it seems to work so I'll accept your answer